# how to output a bootstrap dropdown list on two columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

if the list is more than 6 pieces I want to create a new column in its right side(for example if the list exceeds 12 objects should be created 3 columns).
This just in the Desktop version.
to customize this list i'm using bootstrap!
this is my souce code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ t('Categories') }}<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @foreach(siteCategories() as $category)
                        <li><a href="{{ route('category', ['slug' => $category->slug]) }}">{{{ $category->name }}}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ t('Categories') }}<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @foreach(siteCategories() as $category)
                    <li class="col-sm-6"><a href="{{ route('category', ['slug' => $category->slug]) }}">{{{ $category->name }}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
```

Use the grid utilities in the `li` in the dropdown. You would have to do a counter to change that value depending on the number of objects.